# App crashes when changing NSConstraints for UIToolBar

Tags: ios, swift

Essentially I am trying to display a UIToolBar above the keyboard once the textfield is selected.

**I get the following error when selecting that textfield to edit:**

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException',
>   reason: 'Unable to activate constraint with anchors
>    and
>   
>   because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its
>   anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's
>   illegal.'

**In viewDidLoad I do the following:**

```
let toolBar = UIToolbar()
var items = [UIBarButtonItem]()

items.append(
    UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
)

items.append(
    UIBarButtonItem(title: "Tool Bar Text", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(confirmSignature))
)

items.append(
    UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
)

toolBar.setItems(items, animated: true)
toolBar.tintColor = .white
toolBar.barTintColor = UIColor.red



toolBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false


if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    let guide = self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
    toolBar.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    toolBar.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    toolBar.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    toolBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true

}
else {
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: toolBar, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0).isActive = true
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: toolBar, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0).isActive = true
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: toolBar, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0).isActive = true

    toolBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44).isActive = true
}

exampleTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
```

**And as an extension I do the following for when the textfield is selected:**

```
extension myTableViewName: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        if textField == exampleTextField {
            let toolBar = UIToolbar()

            view.addSubview(toolBar)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check valid constraints is exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment these lines ( no common view between textfield acessory and view )

```
let guide = self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
toolBar.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
toolBar.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
toolBar.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

As the toolBar input view will always take the whole width of screen at bottom with the specified height , you can only leave this

```
toolBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
```

Comment: Is there anyway to raise the UIBarButton with  the text "Tool Bar Text" a bit higher to make it centered with the new height?

Answer (score 0):

toolBar is not added to the view as the error message states.

```swift
self.view.addSubview(toolBar)
```

Comment: this will add it to view all the time and disappear when clicking the field even when no click inside the field

Comment: cannot set constraints without adding to the view as as your guide refers to the self.view.

Comment: @Sh_Khan answer seemed to do the trick, do you know if it is possible to now raise `UIBarButtonItem(title: "Tool Bar Text"` a bit higher to center it in the new height?